# Check Status Of A File In While Loop

Tags: c++, fgets, file-monitoring

I have code that monitors a logfile that is constantly changing. The code is currently running fine but when the file is moved or deleted, the code is still trying to read using the file pointer.

```
fr = fopen (filename, "rt");
while (1) {
  if(fgets(buffer, 500, fr) != NULL) {
       //do something  
  } else {
    sleep(1); //wait for data to come
  }
}
```

How can I detect whether the file has been moved/deleted so I can exit?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution on a specific platform ? If it's Linux, you could give `inotify()` a try. It lets you track when a file / directory has been modified, renamed, moved, deleted and you can take appropriate actions.

Comment: yes it linux..lemee give it a try..thnx!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to you try-catch to overcome your problem.
Once the file is moved (which I guess is os dependent, since some os will not allow it as the file is open by another process) you should get an exception and once you catch it you can decide what to do.

(I need to test it but I think that what should happen in your case)